# Pytorch: Set Block-Diagonal Matrix Efficiently?

Tags: python, matrix, pytorch, diagonal

I have a Tensor A of size [N x 3 x 3], and a Matrix B of size [N*3 x N*3]

I want to copy the contents of A -> B, so that the diagonal elements are filled up basically, and I want to do this efficiently:

It should kind of fill up B to look something filled like this:

[image]

So each [i,3,3] fills into each [3x3] part in B diagonally down the line.

How do I do this? As efficiently as possible as this is for a real time application. I could write a CUDA kernel to do this, but I would prefer to do it with some special Pytorch function

Answer (score 3):

Use [`torch.block_diag()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.block_diag.html):

```py
# Setup
A = torch.ones(3,3,3, dtype=int)

# Unpack blocks and apply
B = torch.block_diag(*A)
```

```py
>>> B
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: Do you know anyway of making this work with batches? That is, I have a 4d tensor, and I need a 3d tensor output?

Answer (score -1):

Here is simple (inplace) example, not sure about the performance for really big tensors:

Code:

```
import torch

# Create some tensors
N = 3
A = torch.ones(N, 3, 3)
A[1] *= 2
A[2] *= 3
B = torch.zeros(N*3, N*3)


def diagonalizer(A, B):
    N = A.shape[0]
    i_min = 0
    j_min = 0
    i_max = 3
    j_max = 3

    for t in range(N):
        B[i_min:i_max, j_min:j_max] = A[t]  # NOTE! this is inplace operation

        # do the step:
        i_min += 3
        j_min += 3
        i_max += 3
        j_max += 3


print('before:\n', B, sep='')

diagonalizer(A, B)

print('after:\n', B, sep='')
```

Output:

```
before:
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
after:
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

Comment: Oops, I knew that. Take a look at TensorLy. It is easier than writing CUDA kernel. http://tensorly.org/stable/index.html

Comment: this code is terrible. its better to write your own kernel to setup the matrix