# Diagonal embedding of a batch of matrices in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, diagonal

If you are given a collection of `n x n` matrices say `m` of them, is there a predefined function in pytorch that performs a diagonal embedding on all of these into a larger matrix of dimension `nm x nm`?

To be concrete, what I am looking for is say you have two `2 x 2` identity matrices, then their diagonal embedding into a `4 x 4` matrix would be the identity `4 x 4` matrix.

Something like:

```
torch.block_diag
```

but this expects you to feed each matrix as a separate argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch: Set Block-Diagonal Matrix Efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856333/pytorch-set-block-diagonal-matrix-efficiently)

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't specify how you get your `m` tensors. Let's say you have

```
# channel first tensors
a = torch.ones(4,2,2)
```

or

```
# a list of tensors
a = [torch.ones(2,2) for _ in range(4)]
```

then you can unpack that in `block_diag`:

```
>>> torch.block_diag(*a)

tensor([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.]])
```